# What's the difference between" the topics discussed" and "the discussed topics"?

Tags: grammar

As a non-native speaker, I think those two above mentioned has no difference.
If any, would any of you tell me the subtle difference? 
As far as I am concerned, past participles should be put before nouns except for past participle phrases modifying nouns.

Comment: in the first option, *discussed* could be acting as either a verb or an adjective. In the second, *discussed* can only be an adjective. That's the only difference.

Comment: The past participle here is actually a reduced relative clause -- *topics* [that were] *discussed*.  So probably the more natural construct is after the noun. The more adjectival the participle, the more natural the position before the noun. *Forgotten* probably works both ways.

Comment: @deadrat Nice pithy overview. I was thinking that the attributive usage of 'discussed' is perhaps marginal, but on checking, found 'However, the presiding judge did not avoid dealing with the discussed topics', where the postnominal variant sounds a little garden-pathy. 'However, the presiding judge dealing with the topics discussed ...' would be more so.

Comment: @V0ight I've not found a single example I'd label as a purely verbal or purely adjectival usage. Some are nearer one end, certainly, but I think a gradience analysis fits better.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ; Grammar isn't my strong suit; how exactly is the *discussed* in the second phrase acting as a verb?

Comment: @V0ight Sorry; I was addressing your '[I]n the first option, [postnominal] _discussed_ could be acting as either a verb or an adjective'. (I'm not sure whether you mean there are different schools of thought, or different scenarios, here.)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ; oh, I merely meant that it's ambiguous as to what sort of context the phrase is being used in. For example, if *discussed* acts as a verb: **"The topics discussed the war on terror, the war in the Middle East, etc."**, or as an adjective: **"The topics discussed were on the war on terror, the war in the Middle East, etc."**

Comment: I'd not even considered the personification possibility. I'm sure OP hasn't either; I'm talking about the difference between say 'The topics discussed by the panel that day ...' (pretty verby) and 'The topics discussed seemed far more trivial than the ones on John's list) (more adjectivy). Participles-or-whatever often show in-between characteristics (leading to arguments about classification).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth ~ I see what you mean; I recently wrote an answer on 'famed' vs. 'famous' and how the former originated as a past participle from the archaic use of 'fame' as a verb, and then 'famed' being the past participle came to become an adjective. btw another example of it being used as a verb that doesn't use personification: "The people who followed the topics discussed blah blah blah", *discussed* here referring to the people and not the topics.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. I've tried to think what factors affect the gradience (and as is often the case when I try to think, nothing happens). Your garden-path argument is on target, and I'd say semantic shifts for phrasal verbs is another factor: *Newspapers put out daily make more money than weeklies* works, but *Put-out newspapers* doesn't. The latter makes the newspapers seem out of sorts. The most adjectival usage I can think of is *bated breath*, where we don't use the obsolete verb *to bate* meaning to hold or delay.  *Unwarranted assumption* is close.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between "discussed topics" and "topics discussed" depends on how the two words are positioned in the overall text.

English is a *spoken* language.  Rhythm and emphasis have meaning.  However, sometimes this is hard to represent in written form, especially for non-native speakers, who may not "hear the words in their heads" as the writer originally imagined them.

English is very flexible in its word placement, and this makes it possible for the writer with a sense of rhythm to place the most important word at a point in the sentence where the emphasis would be natural.

For example, imagine someone attending a meeting on global warming, and describing the experience to a friend:

- Well, the *discussed* topics were all about agriculture.  No one seemed to care about the fishery at all.  Our group couldn't even get on the agenda.  *versus*,
- Well, the *topics* discussed were pretty technical, but all the parties had tables in the hallways, and there were always people standing around them.

In the first case, the sense is that there were some topics discussed and some topics **not** discussed.  The speaker wants to emphasize this before moving on to the next thought.

In the second case, the sense is that the topics had some common property, but that their discussion is less important.

There is no written grammatical rule to guide you on this, in part because the violation of conventional phrasing is often used to create a more memorable phrase.

To improve your ear, you could try [Vital Speeches of the Day](https://www.vsotd.com/).  It takes a little work to find the best examples, but in each case you are looking at words that were meant to be spoken aloud, written by people with a good sense of the language.  The printed speeches are speeches printed, if you get my drift.

Answer (score -1):

If the difference is treated as a grammar or syntax problem rather than a semantic problem, you will have different solutions.  If the phrase was "the articles discussed" versus "the discussed articles" we might have a semantic problem given that we might we concerned about what the articles discussed versus what articles were discussed. With "topics" we do not appear to have that same type of semantic problem.